# Ajax: Getting a Post Error when trying to use Relative Path

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, relative-path

Struggling to get the relative path of an Ajax post request to pickup the php file. I'm not getting an error just nothing happens.

Browsed this site, but cannot find a previous answer on Ajax relative paths that I understand. Still a novice at this. Would really appreciate it, if someone could explain it in layman terms.

I'm trying to access the php file 'search/search.php' from the root file 'index.php' (this file contains the Ajax request). This worked when both files were in the same directory.

File structure below:

[image: project folder structure]

JQuery code snippet:

```
$(function() {
  $('form').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#error').text(""); // reset
    var name = $.trim($("#search").val());
    if (name.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
      $('#error').text('Please enter letters and spaces only');
      return false;
    }
    if (name === '') {
      $('#error').text('Please enter some text');
      return false;
    }
    if (name.length > 0 && name.length < 3) {
      $('#error').text('Please enter more letters');
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'search/search.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        msg: name
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {

      $(".content").html("")
      $(".total").html("")

        if(response){
          var total = response.length;
          $('.total') .append(total + " Results");
         }

        $.each(response, function() {
          $.each($(this), function(i, item) {

            var mycss = (item.Type == 1) ? ' style="color: #ffa449;"' : '';
            $('.content').append('<div class="post"><div class="post-text"> ' + item.MessageText + ' </div><div class="post-action"><input type="button" value="Like" id="like_' + item.ID + '_' + item.UserID + '" class="like" ' + mycss + ' /><span id="likes_' + item.ID + '_' + item.UserID + '">' + item.cntLikes + '</span></div></div>');
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try like this `search/search.php` and see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59918008/12232340

Comment: @Dilek thank you. When I make the recommend change nothing happens (no errors).

Comment: @Dilek The answer you reference, what am I looking for? I can't see how it relates. Sorry.

Comment: Try adding a dot `.` right before `search`: `./search/search.php`.

Comment: @VasilisG. Thank you. I amended the code to url: './search/search.php' and nothing has happened.

Comment: Perhaps you are using some kind of url rewriting?  What is the content of `.htaccess` or `web.config`?

Comment: @TimMorton sorry I don’t even know what that is.

Comment: @CGarden you are working on localhost and localhost has a `/` at the end as defauit  so your url should be like I said in my first comment `search/search.php` without `/`, I refered that link to you to see how url is added in ajax, and check that post as an example to check your codes, as you dont show us any code.

Comment: @Dilek ok thank you. I cant get it to work using your edit. The code I had was working fine when I had it in the same folder as index.php. When I moved search.php under the folder search, I got the issue.

Comment: The leading forward slash simply means begin at the document root, which is where `index.php` lives. So `/search/search.php` should be correct.  If the server is unable to find the file, it stands to reason that there must be some url rewriting happening. If you’re using apache, this can happen either in the virtual host config file, or in the .htaccess file (located in the document root directory; the dot makes it a hidden file). You can test by simply pointing your browser to `http://localhost:8000/search/search.php`. If you get a 404, you know it has nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: BTW, when you edited out the part about getting a 404 error, you took out the single most important clue about what’s happening...

Comment: @TimMorton thank you. That's really helpful. I'm using the Abyss web server. :)

Comment: @TimMorton I've done as you have recommend. Loading search.php through the abyss server I'm getting error: Warning: include(detail/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/Abyss Web Server/htdocs/talk/search/search.php on line 5. I use an include file in search.php, which has the details to log on to MySQL. The include file is pointing at the folder detail which is at the same level as the search folder. I've got this file path wrong I assume. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: my pleasure. Something you might consider at this point is to look in to url rewriting, which can route all (or some) requests through index.php. This reduces relative url confusion, and also allows you to put all your code in a directory that does not have the document root in its path. That’s off topic for this post, but would be well worth looking in to.

Comment: @TimMorton thank you for the tip, appreciate it. I’ll have a look at that for sure.

Comment: @TimMorton do you want to put your comment as the answer then I’ll agree it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading forward slash simply means “begin at the document root”, which is where `index.php` lives. So `/search/search.php` should be correct. If the server is unable to find the file, it stands to reason that there must be some url rewriting happening.

You can test by simply pointing your browser to `http://localhost:8000/search/search.php`. If you get a 404, you know it has nothing to do with ajax